# PHP syntax highlighter - objecto DOM não actualiza o HTML

Tags: php, string, php-domdocument

Tenho estado a desenvolver um código para fazer *syntax highlighting*, mas o código está a falhar a actualizar o HTML.

O código é extenso, e infelizmente todo ele é necessário.

Tenho um ficheiro principal chamado `highlight.php`:

```php
<?php

final class highlight {

    private static $langs = array();
    private static $exts = array();
    private static $default_replace = array(
            'tag'=>'span',
            'text'=>'$1'
        );

    static function highlight_string($lang, $code) {
        if(isset(self::$langs[$lang]))
        {
            $lang_defs = &self::$langs[$lang];

            $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

            $element = $dom->createElement('code', $code);

            $element->setAttribute('class','highlight '.$lang);

            $dom->appendChild($element);

            foreach($lang_defs as $k=>&$lang_def)
            {
                $html = '';

                while($child = &$element->firstChild)
                {

                    if($child->nodeType === 3)
                    {

                        if(!isset($lang_def['replace']))
                        {
                            $lang_def['replace'] = self::$default_replace;
                        }

                        switch(gettype($lang_def['replace']))
                        {
                            case 'string':
                                $html .= preg_replace(
                                        $lang_def['match'],
                                        $lang_def['replace'],
                                        $child->nodeValue
                                    );
                                break;
                            case 'array':
                                $html .= preg_replace(
                                        $lang_def['match'],
                                        '<' . $lang_def['replace']['tag'] .
                                        ' class="' . $lang_def['class'] . '">' .
                                            $lang_def['replace']['text'] .
                                        '</' . $lang_def['replace']['tag'] . '>',
                                        $child->nodeValue
                                    );
                                break;
                            case 'object':
                                $html .= preg_replace_callback(
                                        $lang_def['match'],
                                        $lang_def['replace'],
                                        $child->nodeValue
                                    );
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $html .= $child->nodeValue;
                    }

                    $element->removeChild($child);

                }

                if($html)
                {
                    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();

                    $fragment->appendXML(isset($lang_def['patch'])?$lang_def['patch']($html):$html);

                    $element->appendChild($fragment);

                    if($element->nodeValue == $code)
                    {
                        trigger_error('Syntax highlight failed on the rule no. '.$k.', for the language '.$lang,E_USER_WARNING);

                        return false;
                    }

                    echo '<br>',htmlentities($dom->saveXML()),'<br>',var_dump($element);
                }
            }

            //removes the xml declaration
            return trim(
                    str_replace(
                        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>',
                        '',
                        $dom->saveXML()
                    ),
                    "\r\n"
                );

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static function highlight_file($file) {

        if(@is_file($file))
        {
            if(preg_match('@(?P<file>.*)\.(?P<ext>[^\.]*)$@', $file, $name) && isset(self::$langs[$name['ext']]))
            {
                return self::highlight_string(self::$langs[$name['ext']], file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static function add_lang($lang, $defs){
        switch(gettype($defs)){
            case 'string':
                $defs = (array)include($defs);
                if( $defs === array() )
                {
                    return false;
                }
            case 'array':

                self::$langs[$lang] = $defs['lang'];

                foreach( $defs['exts'] as $ext)
                {
                    self::$exts[$ext] = $lang; 
                }

                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static function lang_loaded($lang) {
        return isset(self::$langs[$lang]);
    }

};
```

Este é o ficheiro onde está a falha. Constantemente corre a função `trigger_error()`.
A função corre quando o código html é o mesmo que o código original, indicando que a função falhou.

As definições são carregadas em ficheiros à parte, um exemplo para o ficheiro `sql.php`:

```php
<?php
    return array(
        'exts'=>array('sql'),
        'lang'=>array(

            array(
                'class'=>'string',
                'match'=>'/([bn]?"(?:[^"]|[\\"]")*"|[bn]?\'(?:[^\']|[\\\']\')*\')(?=[\b\s\(\),;\$#\+\-\*\/]|$)/'
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'comment',
                'match'=>'/((?:\/\/|\-\-\s|#)[^\r\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])*(?:\*\/|$))/',
                'patch'=>function($html){
                    //step one: try to fix the spans
                    $html = preg_replace(
                            '/((?:\/\/|\-\-\s|#)[^\r\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])*(?:\*\/|$))/',
                            '$1</span>',
                            $html
                        );

                    //step 2: fix single-line comments (-- and #)
                    $html = preg_replace_callback(
                            '/<span class="comment">((?:#|-- |\/\/)(?:.|<\/span><span class="[^"]+">([^<])<\/span>)*)([\r\n]|$)/',
                            function($matches){
                                return '<span class="comment">'.
                                    //cleans up all spans
                                    preg_replace(
                                            '/<\/?span(?: class="[^"]+")?>/',
                                            $matches[1].$matches[2],
                                            ''
                                        ).'</span>'.$matches[3];
                            },
                            $html
                        );

                    //step 3: fix multi-line comments
                    return preg_replace_callback(
                            '/<span class="comment">(\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])+(?:\*\/(?:<\/span>)?|$))/',
                            function($matches){
                                return '<span class="comment">'.
                                    //cleans up all spans
                                    preg_replace(
                                        '/<\/?span(?: class="[^"]+")?>/',
                                        $matches[1],
                                        ''
                                    ).'</span>';
                            },
                            $html
                        );
                }
            ),
            array(
                /*
                 * numbers aren't that 'regular' and many edge-cases were left behind    
                 * with the help of @MLM (http://stackoverflow.com/users/796832/mlm),    
                 * we were able to make this work.    
                 * he took over the regex and patched it all up, I did the replace string    
                 */
                'match'=>'/((?:^|\b|\(|\s|,))(?![a-z_]+)([+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE]-?\d+)?)((?=$|\b|\s|\(|\)|,|;))/',
                'replace'=>'$1<span class="number">$2</span>$3'
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'name',
                'match'=>'/(`[^`]+`)/'
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'var',
                'match'=>'/(@@?[a-z_][a-z_\d]*)/'
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'keyword',
                //the keyword replace must have an aditional check (`(?!\()` after the name), due to the function replace()
                'match'=>'/\b(accessible|add|all|alter|analyze|and|as|asc|asensitive|before|between|bigint|binary|blob|both|by|call|cascade|case|change|char|character|check|collate|column|condition|constraint|continue|convert|create|cross|current_date|current_time|current_timestamp|current_user|cursor|database|databases|day_hour|day_microsecond|day_minute|day_second|dec|decimal|declare|default|delayed|delete|desc|describe|deterministic|distinct|distinctrow|div|double|drop|dual|each|else|elseif|enclosed|escaped|exists|exit|explain|false|fetch|float|float4|float8|for|force|foreign|from|fulltext|generated|get|grant|group|having|high_priority|hour_microsecond|hour_minute|hour_second|if|ignore|in|index|infile|inner|inout|insensitive|insert|int|int1|int2|int3|int4|int8|integer|interval|into|io_after_gtids|io_before_gtids|is|iterate|join|key|keys|kill|leading|leave|left|like|limit|linear|lines|load|localtime|localtimestamp|lock|long|longblob|longtext|loop|low_priority|master_bind|master_ssl_verify_server_cert|match|maxvalue|mediumblob|mediumint|mediumtext|middleint|minute_microsecond|minute_second|mod|modifies|natural|nonblocking|not|no_write_to_binlog|null|numeric|on|optimize|optimizer_costs|option|optionally|or|order|out|outer|outfile|parse_gcol_expr|partition|precision|primary|procedure|purge|range|read|reads|read_write|real|references|regexp|release|rename|repeat|replace(?!\()|require|resignal|restrict|return|revoke|right|rlike|schema|schemas|second_microsecond|select|sensitive|separator|set|show|signal|smallint|spatial|specific|sql|sqlexception|sqlstate|sqlwarning|sql_big_result|sql_calc_found_rows|sql_small_result|ssl|starting|stored|straight_join|table|terminated|then|tinyblob|tinyint|tinytext|to|trailing|trigger|true|undo|union|unique|unlock|unsigned|update|usage|use|using|utc_date|utc_time|utc_timestamp|values|varbinary|varchar|varcharacter|varying|virtual|when|where|while|with|write|xor|year_month|zerofill)\b/i'
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'func',
                'match'=>'/\b([a-z_][a-z_\d]*)\b(?=\()/i'
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'name',
                'match'=>'/\b([a-z\_][a-z_\d]*)\b/i'
            )
        )
    );
```

Isto tudo é chamado no ficheiro `index.php`:

```php
<style>
.highlight, .highlight *{
    background:black;
    color:white;
    font-family:'Consolas',monospace;
    font-size:16px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /*forces whitespace to stay there*/
    white-space: pre;
}

.highlight.sql .keyword{color:teal;}
.highlight.sql .string{color:red;}
.highlight.sql .func{color:purple;}
.highlight.sql .number{color:#0F0;}
.highlight.sql .name{color:olive;}
.highlight.sql .var{color:green;}
.highlight.sql .comment{color:gray;}
</style>

Testing highlight of a string:

<?php

    include('highlight.php');

    highlight::add_lang('sql','lang/sql.php');

    echo highlight::highlight_string('sql','select 1,"2";');

?>
```

Que deveria fazer `echo` do seguinte html:

```
<code class="highlight sql"><span class="keyword">select</span> <span class="number">1</span>,<span class="string">"2"</span>;</code>
```

Portanto, a estrutura final de ficheiros é a que se segue:

```
/
|--- index.php
|--- highlight.php
|--- /lang/
     |--- sql.php
     |--- ...
```

Já tentei imensas experiências e todas falharam.

Uma delas foi o seguinte código:

```
<?

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$element = $dom->createElement('code', 'select 1,"2","test"; #test');

$element->setAttribute('class','highlight');

$dom->appendChild($element);

while($element->childNodes->length){
    $element->removeChild($element->firstChild);
}

$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();

$fragment->appendXML('<span class="dest">select</span> 1,"2","test"; ');

$element->appendChild($fragment);

echo '<br>',htmlentities($dom->saveXML());
```

Que funciona! E é bastante semelhante!
O código é gerado correctamente, mas nunca é actualizado o HTML da tag `code`.

O que é que estou a fazer de errado no código?